# Какой самый быстрый алгоритм распаковки данных?

Tags: алгоритм, производительность, архивация

Какой самый быстрый алгоритм **распаковки** информации? Вот прям чтобы real-time и скорость доступа к упакованным данным не сильно падала. Скорость сжатия данных не важна.

Comment: а вам что паковать файлы или поток ?

Comment: тоже неважно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос конечно...

Самый гарантированно быстрый алгоритм распаковки (да и сжатия тоже) чего угодно, причем 100% потоковый - это RLE ))

Условно шустрый и условно-потоковой - это DEFLATE. Его большой плюс - стандартность - то есть куча библиотек по самые разные языки.

Если говорить о видео-аудио данных - то нужно подбирать то, что может быть распакованно на большинстве клиентов аппаратно. Тогда конечная произодительность алгоритма не будет иметь решающего значения. Я бы копал в сторону ранних реализаций H.264...

Comment: Спасибо, почитал в википедии, немного не понял: 

> Кодирование повторов — простой
> алгоритм сжатия данных, который
> оперирует сериями данных, то есть
> последовательностями, в которых один и
> тот же **символ** встречается
> несколько раз подряд.

 И другое определение на той же википедии 

> Кодирование длин серий (Групповое кодирование, также известен как англ. RLE) — последовательная серия одинаковых элементов заменяется на два символа: **элемент** и число его повторений

так все таки только символ или вообще любой неделимый элемент?
А что не так с главным вопросом?)

Comment: Ну, эээ... Самый быстрый — это вообще не сжимать. Скорость произвольного гарантировано не падает :-)

Comment: 2 VladD. Улыбнуло)

Comment: 2wefwefgwe

"так все таки только символ или вообще любой неделимый элемент?"

Гы. Ну, в принципе зависит от того, насколько сложный анализатор вы хотите делать.

Обычно говорят о символе. Кодировать можно и последовательности, но это усложняет семантику потока и очень усложняет кодировщик.

Далее. Подобный алгоритм имеет смысл только в не сжатых данных - текст, ВМР, WAV и т.п. Причем с очень разной эффективностью.

Comment: 2wefwefgwe

"А что не так с главным вопросом?)"

От того, что вы планируете кодировать сильно зависит - как. А Ваш вопрос задан очень в общем виде, и вместо того, чтобы ответить по сути - нам (отвечающим, включая меня;)) приходится думать, что бы вы хотели спросить)


Резюме: болтать об алгоритмах можно долго. Но если вам нужен быстрый результат то подбираете наиболее популярное для вашей задачи (текст, видео, звук) и юзаете. И будет вам счастье.

Comment: ну значит просто надо было уточнить в вопросе что данные нужно все таки сжать, неважно каким алгоритмом, главное чтобы доступ к упакованным данным был максимально быстрым из имеющихся способов. Вот еще нашел [http://fastcompression.blogspot.ru/p/lz4.html][1] , вдруг кому пригодится.


  [1]: http://RealTime Data Compression

Answer (score 0):

[LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/)

Очень быстрая, есть вариант в виде всего двух файликов, .c и .h. Вроде есть возможность использовать из некоторых других языков